# Spark iterate over RDD grouped by keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I've to develop a Spark application, I have to use Spark 1.3 and so I can't use window functions. I've chosen to iterate over single groups of elements, created grouping by key the rdd. The solution I found so far is to collect the keys and then to take the corresponding RDD with a lookup(key). I know that my approach is very inefficient, but I don't know how to apply my function that converts the RDD to a list and then returns another list in another way.

```
logon_dhcp = logons.map(lambda logon: (logon.user, (logon.dhcpscopename, logon.city, logon.timestamp)))
logon_dhcp = logon_dhcp.groupByKey()

dhcp_change_list = []
for key in logon_dhcp.keys().collect():
    new_list = dhcp_changed(key,logon_dhcp.lookup(key))
    dhcp_change_list = list(set().union(dhcp_change_list,new_list))

def dhcp_changed(key,group):
    values = list(group[0])
    values_sorted = sorted(values, key=lambda tup: tup[2])
    prevCity = None
    prevValue = None
    prevTime = None
    res = list()
    for value in values_sorted:
        if prevCity != None and prevCity != value[1] and notEnoughTime(prevTime,value[2]):
            res.append((key, prevTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), prevCity, value[2].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), value[1]))
        prevCity = value[1]
        prevTime = value[2]
        prevValue = value
    return res
```

How I can do the same thing with like an aggregateByKey()?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a simple map works, since the RDD is already in the format ( key, IterableList)

```
result = logon_dhcp.map(lambda x: dhcp_changed(x))
```

with the function modified as:

```
def dchp_changed(group):
    key = str(group[0])
    values = list(group[1])
```

Any suggestion to improve my code's performance is welcome